# Switching background image via CSS on screen width

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
#section-one {
    background: url('http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-pointers.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    #section-one {
        background: url('http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-880px.jpg') !important;
    }
}
```

Now I was expecting this to change the background image when the browser width is <=800px

Nothing actually changes though, but if I right click and view image when the browser is below 800px width, it actually shows me the 800px width image?

Strange, why is this happening and how do I fix it? Here is the link should you need it:

```
http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk
```

The only other CSS I have for #section-one I have is:-

```
@media all and (max-width: 880px) {
    /* Section 1 */
    #section-one {
        margin-bottom: -49px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anything else controlling it? i mean, maybe somewhere in the rest of your css code or on the element directly you added a width to it... please include code, adding a link may not help others in the future visiting this question as the link could be taken down or otherwise unavailable...

Comment: I get a 404 when I access http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-800px.jpg. The real reason nothing appears to change, though, is because you have an <img> element pointing to the same image as your first CSS rule covering the #section-one area.

Comment: http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-880px.jpg - still the same

Comment: ahh - I forgot I changed this to an image, thanks!

Comment: I would highly, highly, HIGHLY recommend validating your code. You have tons of incorrect or missing closing tags, and a lot of generally not-so-good coding habits. Take a look at [w3's validator's recommendations for your site](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F176.67.174.179%2Fukcctvinstallations.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: I think you are displaying the images both as background and in image tag. so once the width changes to <=880px, the background changes and not the image tag. That is why it showing the image even you remove the background image. I dont know exactly but I am guessing that this might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can create a picture in the standard sizes of screen like `section-one.jpg (1440x900)` and then use this code for your `#section-one` :

> ## #section-one{
>
> ```
> min-width:974px;
> min-height:510px;
> background:url(section-one.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed transparent;
> -webkit-background-size:cover;
> -moz-background-size:cover;
> -o-background-size:cover;
> background-size:cover;
> height:100%;
> width:100%;
> image-rendering:optimizeSpeed
> ```
>
> ## }

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this code

@media only screen 
and (max-width :800px) {

 #section-one{ 

 background: url(section-one.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;

 -webkit-background-size: cover;

 -moz-background-size: cover;

 -o-background-size: cover;

 background-size: cover;

 width:100%;

 height:100%;
 }
 }
```